# Creating custom boxed footnotes (with symbolic / numeric marks)

Tags: footnotes, tcolorbox, boxes, customize

I'm trying to create custom footnotes for a project, where we need to have the options of using a symbolic footnote, and using a numeric footnote where the text appears inside a box.
Using the bigfoot package I've so far managed to make the different footnote types and to place the numeric footnote text inside a box, however the footnote mark appears outside and above the box. Is there a way to place it inside?

Here's the relevant code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 


\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{symb}[fnsymbol]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{num}

\newcommand{\boxedfootnote}[1]{%
   \footnotenum{%
      \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=lightgray,colframe=white, boxrule=0.5pt]%
      #1%
      \end{tcolorbox}%
   }%
}

\begin{document}
Text with numeric footnote \footnotenum{This is a numeric footnote.}.\\
Text with symbolic footnote \footnotesymb{This is a symbolic footnote.}.\\
Text with a boxed footnote \boxedfootnote{This is a boxed footnote.}.
\end{document}
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated, I'm very new to this so I'm mostly guessing what to do.

Comment: As always on the site you are much more likely to get any help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Here we have to add stuff in order to test your code...

Comment: Hi @daleif, I edited the post so I believe now you can copy and run it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this give what you want. Don't need `bigfoot` package. Directly redefine the `\@footnotetext` in a group. And using redefined `\thefootnote` in a group along with `\footnotemark[n]` and `footnotetext[n]` to type the symbolic footnote.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 

\newcounter{symbcount}
\newcommand{\footnotesymb}[1]{%
{\stepcounter{symbcount}\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnotemark[\thesymbcount]\footnotetext[\thesymbcount]{#1}}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\boxedfootnote}[1]{%
{\long\def\@footnotetext##1{\insert\footins{%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \def\@currentcounter{footnote}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark
    }%
    \color@begingroup%
      \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=lightgray,colframe=white, boxrule=0.5pt,left=-3pt,right=-3pt,nobeforeafter]\@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces##1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \par\end{tcolorbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}\footnote{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Text with numeric footnote\footnote{test}

Text with symbolic footnote\footnotesymb{This is a symbolic footnote.}.

Text with a boxed footnote\boxedfootnote{This is a boxed footnote.}

Text with symbolic footnote\footnotesymb{This is a symbolic footnote.} again.

Text with numeric footnote\footnote{test} again.
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

> update: Simply the code to make the tcolorbox have better alignment. And now the code is compatible with `hyperref` package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 

\newcounter{symbcount}
\newcounter{oldfootnote}
\newcommand{\footnotesymb}[1]{%
{\setcounter{oldfootnote}{\thefootnote}\setcounter{footnote}{\thesymbcount}\stepcounter{symbcount}\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnotemark\footnotetext{#1}\setcounter{footnote}{\theoldfootnote}}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\boxedfootnote}[1]{%
{\let\old@footnotetext\@footnotetext\long\def\@footnotetext##1{\let\old@makefntext\@makefntext\let\@makefntext\relax\old@footnotetext{\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=lightgray,colframe=white, boxrule=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,boxsep=0pt,nobeforeafter]\old@makefntext ##1\end{tcolorbox}}}\footnote{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Text with numeric footnote\footnote{test}

Text with symbolic footnote\footnotesymb{This is a symbolic footnote.}.

Text with a boxed footnote\boxedfootnote{This is a boxed footnote.}. 

Text with symbolic footnote\footnotesymb{This is a symbolic footnote.} again.

Text with numeric footnote\footnote{test} again.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Tom, thank you very much! I don't really understand much of what's going on there but it works great. A few additional queries: is there a way to order the appearance of the footnotes (symbolic first, numeric, and boxed last)? It worked when I used bigfoot but I don't know how to do it with these boxed footnotes (importing bigfoot makes the boxed ones go first, not last). Also, is there a way to specify which symbol to use in symbolic footnotes? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @KonstantinosTopaloglou, I don't know how to do the order like `bigfoot` package. Probably you need define each `footins` insert manually. I guess it was not easy based on my knowledge. You can ask another question. I updated the code in my answer to make the tocolorbox have better alignment and settings. Also the code is now compatible with `hyperref` package.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{tcolorbox} 

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{symb}[fnsymbol]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{num}

\newcommand{\boxedfootnote}[1]{%
    \footnotenum{%
    %   \vspace{-.5 cm}
        \fbox{#1}
        
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    Text with numeric footnote \footnotenum{This is a numeric footnote.}.\\
    Text with symbolic footnote \footnotesymb{This is a symbolic footnote.}.\\
    Text with a boxed footnote \boxedfootnote{This is a boxed footnote.}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Raffaele, thank you for the answer! One thing that I'm missing here is that I'm looking to make the footnote mark appear inside the box along with the text, as is done in the other answer.

Comment: @KonstantinosTopaloglou The Tom's answer its very pro (guru). Not for me. In any case I am glad You have the correct answer.